# How to find out how is curl getting its proxy

Tags: curl, proxy, suse

I have a SUSE Linus and when I run curl it is using a proxy (without any proxy-related parameters passed).

Where can I find the proxy configuration?

I checked the http_proxy/https_proxy environment variables but they are not configured. 
Also there is no configuration in the /etc/sysconfig/proxy file.
Actually I printed the whole environment and found no proxy configuration (i.e. the used proxy host and port) present there.

Is there some other way that curl can read a proxy configuration?

Comment: Please provide the exact command(s) used and the outputs that makes you believe that curl is using a proxy.

Comment: @ckujau I get an error page from the proxy that the host was not found. This is expected because the host is in the internal network and should be called directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your curl config file may be forcing a proxy even if the environment isn't.

Look for the file `~/.curlrc` and see if it has a `proxy = ....` line in it.

You can also try using curl without a config file: `curl -q http://the.site.com` and see if you get the same error from the proxy. (The `-q` **must** be the first parameter given, or it reads the default config file anyway.)

Lastly, since you have an internal network, is the gateway forcing a proxy? You can't stop that from your machine, network admin will have to fix that.

Luck.